# How can I create a restaurant order menu with dish options?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently working on a restaurant menu ordering website and I am stuck on adding dish options to certain dishes. I use radio buttons to let the user choose their preferred option:

`<label class="option"><input type="radio" value="Ketchup"> Ketchup</label>` etc ...

Then, I have an add button which is an link with an onclick attribute which then runs a function. How can i pass the checked radio box value through the function without a form ?

Comment: What exactly is wrong? Clicking the label won't change the selection, you cannot access the radio button data when the form is submitted?

Comment: @lpd clicking the label WILL change the selection if the html is structured right. Labels on radios and checkboxed add extra usability features for mouse users in exactly that way.

Comment: @Trey I was just trying to brainstorm potential problems the user is having, not describe what is actually happening. At the moment the user hasn't actually posed a problem, just a statement.

Comment: fair enough... it sounded like a statement followed by a question, just making sure;)

Comment: @Qiang Seriously now, you have an `<input>` and you want to handle it, but you can't use a `<form>`? WHY??

Comment: Why `radio`? Why not a series of `checkbox`es? Also, I assume you're trying to make a dynamic "cart" of selected options for a selected dish? @MrLister - I'm hoping that's a confused statement by the OP; for instance, maybe the approach is a popup to select and then "pass" the options back to the `form`, but they're not "in" the form when selected.

Comment: Wow, what an opionated set of comments this question has

Comment: @machineghost We're just trying to understand the scope of the problem. Reactions like "you can't be serious!" are just part of the process.

Comment: @Mr Lister They can  be part of the process.  Or you could try and be respectful to fellow SO members, take the high road, and if you have to ask a question like that, phrase it more diplomatically, eg. "It seems like a form would be helpful in solving this problem; why is it important to you that you not use a form?"  One of the things I love most about Stack Overflow is how the community that exists here encourages all of us to elevate our level of dialogue.

Comment: @machineghost Sorry if I rubbed you the wrong way, but it's just that I'm allergic to questions that say "I want to do [something], but I don't want to use [normal way to do it]". Unless it's interview questions; in that case the answer is "strangle the interviewer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click the add button, it has no idea what radio button got selected, so you can't really "pass the checked radio box vale through".  What you can do though is just check the value from inside the function, if you give your radios a class that lets you reference them.  With a class of say "dish", the jquery code for that would be:

```
$('.dish:checked').val();
```

Comment: Normally I despise answers that shove jquery down your throat, but this type of scenario sounds like a reasonable situation to import a library. I would add though, you could use `label.option > *`

Comment: Honestly, I would have included a non-jQuery solution, since the question had no jQuery tag, but I was typing the answer on a tablet and the jQuery version was sooooo much shorter in this case :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you give your form elements IDs, like so:

```
<label class="option"><input type="radio" id="radioButton1" value="Ketchup"> Ketchup</label>
```

Then you can easily access the values of your radio buttons through the DOM. I would not use a parameter but a local variable, like so:

```
function myFunction {
    var myValue;
    if (document.getElementById('radioButton1').checked == true) {
        myValue = document.getElementById('radioButton1').value;
    }
    else {
        // Check other radio buttons
    }
    // Perform some function using myValue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the input "Radio Buttons" an id with an onClick event on each one that, when the button is clicked, will run the function the event is attached to.